# convert UTM to lat/long or vice versa

Tags: r, geospatial, gdal, rgdal

I downloaded elevation data for New Zealand in the form of a tif file, which is accompanied by a "world file" (`tfw`),

```
80.000000000000000
0.000000000000000
0.000000000000000
-80.000000000000000
1062571.750000000000000
6282711.000000000000000
```

My understanding from wikipedia is that the first and third numbers indicate the scale (pixels/km), and the last two locate the origin in UTM coordinates (if I understand correctly).

Now, I would like to align these raster data with a different data set comprising a path traced from GPS coordinates, which give me a lat/long format

```
       X         Y
1 174.7771 -41.29805
2 174.7771 -41.29815
3 174.7772 -41.29819
4 174.7772 -41.29824
5 174.7772 -41.29827
6 174.7772 -41.29836
...
```

I've tried the following to convert from UTM to lat/long, but the results seem completely wrong. What am I missing?

```
library(rgdal)
utm <- SpatialPoints(cbind(1062571.75, -6282711.0), 
                       proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm"))
spTransform(utm, CRS("+proj=nzmg"))

class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 1 
extent      : 1754874408, 1754874408, 5271325323, 5271325323  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=nzmg +ellps=WGS84
```

Edit: following the suggestion below I got the following data from the tif file,

```
> library(raster)
> r <- raster("nztm.tif")
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 19712, 13261, 261400832  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 80, 80  (x, y)
extent      : 1062532, 2123412, 4705791, 6282751  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : nztm.tif 
names       : nztm 
values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)

> crs(r)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000
+ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if the file comes with a coordinate reference system (perhaps in a .prj file?)
In R, you can do:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster("elevation.tif")
r
crs(r)
```

If that is NA, and you cannot find any reference elsewhere, it may be very difficult to figure this out.

It may be that the elevation crs is "UTM" but that is not guaranteed at all. If it is UTM, you need to know which of the 60 UTM zones and then there may be some other parameters. It is actually highly unlikely that someone would choose UTM for New Zealand as the country crosses multiple UTM zones. You could try this:

```
library(rgdal)
utm <- SpatialPoints(cbind(1062571.75, -6282711.0), 
                       proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=59 +datume=WGS84 "))
spTransform(utm, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
#SpatialPoints:
#     coords.x1 coords.x2
#[1,] -179.8818 -56.35255
```

Not *that* far from NZ.

"nzmg" or another standard crs for NZ would be more plausible

```
utm <- SpatialPoints(cbind(1062571.75, -6282711.0), 
                       proj4string=CRS("+proj=nzmg +datum=WGS84"))
spTransform(utm, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# -178.9791  -71.8877
```

Even further, alas, almost Antarctica

Comment: ah! What do you know, I didn't even think of looking for metadata in the tif file. Indeed, `crs(r)` returns useful information, I've edited the original post, thanks!